# Why are my sorted unique counts not writing to the output file in linux?

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, unique

I am trying to extract the coverage counts from a file, and then sort these and have counts of the unique values. The coverage count data is in column 3 of my file.

I have been running this as my job, submitted on a slurm HPC:

```
awk '{print$3}' patient.coverage | sort | uniq -c > patient_coverage_counts
```

However this produces an empty output file and I am unsure why.

When I run `head patient.coverage | awk '{print$3}' | sort | uniq -c` The output prints to the output absolutely fine.

Any help or insight would be hugely appreciated!!

Comment: What does `awk '{print$3}' < patient.coverage | sort | uniq -c > patient_coverage_counts` produce?

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown us your efforts(commands) which you have tried to solve your own problem. Kindly do add sample of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: no error messages? no output from `ls -l patient_coverage_counts` Wow! what are permissions for dir that you are writing too? maybe try `...>/tmp/patient_coverage_counts` ? Good luck

Comment: Given that `head` works, and that this is running on a cluster ... is if tair to assume that `patient.coverage` is constantly written to?  In that case ``awk`|sort` won't stop doing their thing till there's no new output - then they'll flush.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.